# Not Like Operator not working using ACCESS/SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently trying to exclude a comment that has the words "Not Issue" but for some reason it is partially working. When I remove the code below, I get 100 values, but when I add the syntax below it returns 50, but of those 50 fields, there are still some rows that contain "Not Issue".

```
INSERT INTO Combined_Comments ( [ID], [Comment] ) 
SELECT [Comments_001].[ID], IIf([Comments]<>" ","BR
#" & [Branch Number] & " - " & [Comments],[Comments]) AS [Dup Comment] 
FROM [Comments_001] 
WHERE ((Not (IIf([Comments]<>" ","BR #" & [Branch Number] & " - " & [Comments],[Comments]))<>"%not issue%") AND (([Dup Vin Comments_085].[Dup Ind])<>" "));
```

Comment: If you are using MS Access why tag SQL Server?

Comment: I don't see NOT LIKE operator, only "not equal".

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, the like wildcard symbol is '*' while in SQL Server it is '%' so your sql in your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO Combined_Comments ( [ID], [Comment] ) 
SELECT [Comments_001].[ID], IIf([Comments]<>" ","BR
#" & [Branch Number] & " - " & [Comments],[Comments]) AS [Dup Comment] 
FROM [Comments_001] 
WHERE ((Not (IIf([Comments]<>" ","BR #" & [Branch Number] & " - " & [Comments],[Comments])) not like "*not issue*") AND (([Dup Vin Comments_085].[Dup Ind])<>" "));
```

I see a lot of "not" operators and assume the double negatives give you what you need.